# BCC in ItemSend event in Outlook 2007 no longer works

Tags: vba, email, outlook, bcc

I inserted code in `ItemSend` and saved the ThisOutlookSession module.  It worked once and no longer works.  It was saved as VBAproject.OTM and is still there when I open the module after restarting Outlook.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                 Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim strBcc As String
    On Error Resume Next

    ''# #### USER OPTIONS ####
    ''# address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable
    ''# to a name in the address book
    strBcc = "someone@somewhere.dom"

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                 "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    Set objRecip = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW an email address will always resolve, so there would be no need to call the Resolve Method or check its value.

Answer (score 3):

use and if statement on the Item's Subject field

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

If Item.Subject = "exact match" Then

    strBcc = "someone@somewhere.dom"

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
    If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
        strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                 "Do you want still to send the message?"
        res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
        If res = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If


    End If
    Item.Save

    Set objRecip = Nothing


End If
```

or use if you want a contains a word in the subject

```
If InStr(Item.Subject, "BCCSubject") = 0 Then


End If
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're hooking the `ItemSend` event, that should be in a class module with `WithEvents` and your code to call it in a regular module. Also, you'll want to do an `Item.Save` on the message for the BCC to stick.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue recently. It started after the .pst file was corrupted in some way and I had to run scanpst.exe (which I had to search my drive for because the error message does not tell you where it is)

After running scanpst.exe and the issue presented itself, this is how I fixed it.

First, I fiddled with macro security. I set it to the lowest setting. [Here is a link that covers how to change macro security](http://www.slipstick.com/developer.hot-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/). Go to Tools > Macro > Security. I set it to "No security check for Macros."

Then I used this exact code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim objRecip As Recipient
Dim strMsg As String
Dim res As Integer
Dim strBcc As String
On Error Resume Next

' #### USER OPTIONS ####
' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable
' to a name in the address book
strBcc = "PUT YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS HERE AND LEAVE THE QUOTES"

Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
objRecip.Type = olBCC
If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
"Do you want still to send the message?"
res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
"Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
If res = vbNo Then
Cancel = True
End If
End If

Set objRecip = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then I clicked the save button then little green play button to run the macro. It asked me for a Macro name. I used bccUsername and clicked create. The editor added a section called `Modules` under `ThisOutLookSession`.

I then restarted Outlook and tested twice and it worked.

I'm not exactly sure what I did that made it start working again, but this is not too involved with the steps so hopefully this helps you and others with the same problem.